# MLB Ball/Strike data

Tags: data-request, sports

Particularly interested in ball/strike calls for each at-bat along with the batter, pitcher, and umpire name. Any time frame would work. Data on the outcome of the at-bat would also be valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PITCHf/x Search function by Baseball Savant provides search functionality for the MLBAM PITCHf/x database:
http://www.baseballsavant.com/pitchfx_search.php